# How to get images and videos from firebase and show in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am developing a quiz app which is calling questions and options from firebase. It is currently only showing texts in questions and options from the firebase documents. I want it to get the images and videos from firebase and display it on my flutter application. Is it possible? If yes, please guide me through it. Thank you!

This is the code where I am showing the questions from..

```
class QuestionPage extends StatelessWidget {
final Question question;
const QuestionPage({super.key, required this.question});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var state = Provider.of<QuizState>(context);

return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(question.text),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: question.options.map((opt) {
          return Container(
            height: 90,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            color: Colors.black26,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                state.selected = opt;
                _bottomSheet(context, opt, state);
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                        state.selected == opt
                            ? FontAwesomeIcons.circleCheck
                            : FontAwesomeIcons.circle,
                        size: 30),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                        child: Text(
                          opt.value,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
}

/// Bottom sheet shown when Question is answered
_bottomSheet(BuildContext context, Option opt, QuizState state) {
bool correct = opt.correct;

showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 250,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(correct ? 'Good Job!' : 'Wrong'),
          Text(
            opt.detail,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white54),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: correct ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
            child: Text(
              correct ? 'Onward!' : 'Try Again',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                letterSpacing: 1.5,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              if (correct) {
                state.nextPage();
              }
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

[image: I have added 1 image and video in my firebase storage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of things it seems you manually stored the images and videos ( Not programmatically). This means you have to create a collection (if you do not have one already) and input the url for each file you have stored in the database).

For example, If a question document from your **Question collection** has an image, a question text, and the list of options, you have to store the string url of the image in that particular question document.

To get the image string url, click and copy the link:

[image]

Then add it into your collection:
[image]

After doing this, you access your documents in your flutter app and then open the image/video using:

- [Extended Image](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image) (for image).
- [Better Player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player). (for video).

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I will try doing this.